# Multi language and different platform support in Android

Tags: android, localization, version

this question may be a simple one but I just need it clarified. I have worked with localisation in Android with the values-sv, values-fi style before and it works perfectly. I've also been working with platform specific valus like this values-v11, values-v14 and also that has worked very good. Now I need to combine them, I need multilanguage support and different values depending on platform. And I can't get it to work, I've tried this style values-v11-sv and so on.

The reason why I need to do this is because a want to have a different style on my theme depending on platform and that will be configured in a styles.xml file.
One other question I also have is if I need to have all strings.xml files in all version and language maps, or if it just needs to be in the values map with the lowest platform number, I mean the strings should be the same on all platforms.

What's the proper way of implementing this.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `string.xml` files into the language specific directories like `values-fi` and the `styles.xml` files into the version specific directories like `values-v11`.

The strings will then be the same on all API versions and the styles will be the same on all languages.

The approach with version and style specific directories like `values-fi-v11` (note that the language has to be specified first) is only necessary if you want the resource to be only applicable to this specific version and language combination.

See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for full details.

Comment: Thank you for this information, it works perfect!
Very informative link also.